# Yii - reload dynamically added CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

if append to page the CGridView ('myGridViewID') by ajax, I can't reload it.
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('myGridViewID');

> TypeError: settings is undefined
>
> $grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use renderPartial in controller action:

```php
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->reset();
$cs->scriptMap = array(
    'jquery.js'  =>  false,   // prevent produce jquery.js in additional javascript data
);

// Look at 4th parameter: with TRUE value, your view will have additional javascript data.
$this->renderPartial('_partialViewWithGrid', array(), false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wiki for dynamic [CgridViews](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/323/dynamic-parent-and-child-cgridview-on-single-view-using-ajax-to-update-child-gridview-via-controller-after-row-in-parent-gridview-was-clicked) in the same view. That should work.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with dynamically loaded CGridViews (and everything containing ajax) is that CController::renderPartial() does not render the required javascript code for them to work properly, unlike CController::render(), which includes the required layout and JS.

There is [an extension called ZController](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10427-ajax-clientscript/) which offers a workaround for this problem, but due to the way CGridviews are reloaded (by making an ajax call to the same URL)... when you try to filter/sort/page a CGridView loaded via AJAX, the subsequent Ajax call will replace the whole contents of your browser window, but I honestly think that **maybe** (*only maybe*) [this workaround](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/163/avoiding-rendering-entire-page-when-using-cgridview-and-clistview-via-ajax/) could help, but I haven't had the time to try it out.

That is why I currently *avoid loading CGridViews using AJAX*.